# how to trigger a input file with dynamic ref

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following code for rendering a list of file upload input:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="doc in requiredDocuments" :key="doc.key">
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>
            {{ doc.name }}
          </p>
          <p>
            {{ doc.description }}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input :id="`uploader_${doc.key}`" :ref="`uploader_${doc.key}`" :name="`uploader_${doc.key}`" type="file" accept="image/*,.pdf,.doc,.docx,.csv,.xls,.xlsx,.ppt,.pptx" class="sr-only" @change="onChangeFileUpload()" />
          <button @click="$refs[`uploader_${doc.key}`].click()"> Upload </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

As you can see the refs are dynamically created for the hidden file inputs. each file input has an upload, I want to use the upload button to trigger the file upload interaction window.

Howeverm I'm having a problem rendering this HTML, I get this error:

```
TypeError: _ctx.$refs[("uploader_" + (intermediate value))] is undefined
```

Here is a JsFiddle recreation of the error: https://jsfiddle.net/36gyqj8o/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a method in this case

```
<button @click="upload(doc.key)"> Upload </button>
```

and the script block should be like

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      requiredDocuments: [{
          name: 'Study 1',
          key: '1',
          description: 'This is a description for what type of document you need to upload'
        },
        {
          name: 'Study 2',
          key: '2',
          description: 'This is a description for what type of document you need to upload'
        },
        {
          name: 'Study 3',
          key: '3',
          description: 'This is a description for what type of document you need to upload'
        },
        {
          name: 'Study 4',
          key: '4',
          description: 'This is a description for what type of document you need to upload'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
   upload(key) {
     this.$refs[`uploader_${key}`].click();
   },
  },
  template: document.getElementById('main').innerHTML
})

app.mount('#app')
```

Modified js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/b4asugxk/